# Flex Lexer REGEX Optimiser

Tags: flex-lexer

Is there a Flex REGEX optimiser? There is something similar as a perl module:

http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Regexp-Assemble-0.37/

but unfortunately it doesn't support lex regex syntax. Pretty much what I want to do is to have a tool which to optimise the regex

```
TOMA|TOMOV
```

to

```
TOM(A|OV)
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need to do that. Flex compiles the regexes into a single deterministic finite state machine (FSM), and aside from minor cache effects with very large scanner definitions, there is no performance penalty for alternation or repetition operators.

Flex does not minimize the FSM, but that would only reduce the size of the FSM tables, not the speed of lexical analysis (aside from the aforementioned cache effects, if applicable).

Even though the FSM is not minimized, the NFA-to-DFA conversion process will perform the particular transformation you suggest. As a consequence, the follow two rules produce *exactly* the same lexical analyzer:

1. ```
   TOMA|TOMOV { /* do something */ }
   ```
2. ```
   TOM(A|OV)  { /* do something */ }
   ```

Although there is no real performance penalty, you should attempt to avoid the following, which unnecessarily duplicates the action code:

3. ```
   TOMA       { /* do something */ }
   TOMOV      { /* do the same thing */ }
   ```

You might also find the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922376/should-i-avoid-in-flex-patterns) useful.

Comment: Agreed ;-) Thank you ;-)