# How to escape a regex when used in a lex input file?

Tags: regex, lex

I want to use this regex (["'])(?:(?=(\?))\2.)*?\1 from this [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks)

But when I use it in a lex input file as follows:

DOUBLEQUOTE_CONTENTS        (["'])(?:(?=(\?))\2.)*?\1

%%

{DOUBLEQUOTE_CONTENTS}          { printf("here"); }

I get a large number of "unrecognized character" errors from lex. It chokes on the first ? character and many more after that. If I escape the ? characters, the regex doesn't match anymore.

How can I use the said regex in a lex input file?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that may be so, but it's incidental to the question I believe.

Comment: I think you just need to unroll the pattern: `"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'`

Answer (score 1):

(F)lex does not implement lookahead (`(?=...)` and friends) nor non-greedy repetitions (`*?`). And it doesn't have captures so non-capturing parentheses (`(?:...)`) are redundant. And finally, it does not implement back references (`\2`).

In short, you can only use regular expressions which are really regular. See the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) to see what is permitted.

Here's a simple pattern which doesn't depend on lookaheads or backreferences:

```
["]([^"\\]|\\.)*["]|'([^'\\]|\\.)*'
```

Comment: The patter you provide is inefficient because of alternations. I suggest using the regex from my comment above.

Comment: @wiktor: in flex, alternations are free because flex creates a DFA. See this answer, which includes a benchmark: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26922380/1566221