# flex parse symbol - complex symbol

Tags: c++, g++, flex-lexer

I'm new to flex, I'm just trying to parse a number :

```
%{
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  extern int yylex();
%}
%option noyywrap

DIGIT    [0-9]
ID       [a-z][a-z0-9]*
NUM      {DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}* | {DIGIT}+

%%
{NUM}   {printf("Number encountered : %s\n",yytext);}
%%
int main(int, char**) {
  while (yylex());
}
```

When I replace the `Number encountered` line with

```
{DIGIT}+    { printf( "Number %s\n", yytext);}
{DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}*       { printf( "Number %s\n", yytext);}
```

I get output, but now I don't.

*I mean it doesn't parse correctly. It prints out nothing.*

**How can solve this problem?**

Current code :

```
%{
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  extern int yylex();
%}
%option noyywrap

WS  [ \t\n]+
DIGIT    [0-9]
NUM      ({DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}*|{DIGIT}+)
%%
NUM {printf("num : %s\n",yytext);}
%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple just do this :

```
NUMBER  {N}+|{N}+"."{N}+|"."{N}+|{N}+"."
```

Answer (score 0):

Patterns cannot contain unescaped whitespace, so the pattern in your first attempt is invalid.

Remove the spaces around the `|`.

Comment: if i need to use or.. what is the most conventional way to do so ??

Comment: i'm asking this type of que, because i have tried `NUM      ([{DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}*] | [{DIGIT}+])` , from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922380/10305444) of yours.. and it doesn't work... what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: that answer of mine does not contain the pattern you are trying. The basic problem with the pattern in your question is that you put spaces around the `|`. You cannot put spaces in a flex pattern.

Comment: i'm using `NUM      ({DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}*|{DIGIT}+)` and `NUM {printf("num : %s\n",yytext);}` but i get no match

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: the pattern in your comment is completely wrong because `[` and `]` have a different meaning.

Comment: removed `[` and `]`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: go back to the code in your question and only remove the spaces. Don't change several things at once; you just make different errors each time.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad: 1. Don't change questions after they have been answered. 2. This time, you left out the braces in where you try to use the macro `NUM`. That's why I told you to not make multiple changes.